# No such device after installing a ssd (Ubuntu/Win7)

Tags: grub2, windows-7, ssd

I'm having problems to boot into Win7 via Grub after moving my Ubuntu installation to a ssd.

Before I had a single hdd with Ubuntu installed on /dev/sda1 and Win7 on /dev/sda2.

I then installed the ssd as sdb and installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it. Grub detected both installations of Ubuntu and Windows.I was then able to boot into both Installations of Ubuntu, unfortunately I didn't try Windows.

Later I removed the Ubuntu version on the hdd but left the Windows partition untouched. I now have the following configuration:

**/dev/sda**

sda1 : An ext4 partition for media

sda2 : Win7 flagged as bootable

**/dev/sdb**

Ubuntu 15.10 flagged bootable with Grub installed

Ubuntu is working just fine but when I try to boot into Windows I'm getting

> error: no such device: UUID XXXXX

I already checked the UUID in `grub.conf`, it matches the UUID `blkid` gives me (without the PARTUUID).

I hardly need the Windows installation, so I could live with a workaround...

**Edit:**

I already ran sudo update-grub with no effect. Windows is found but when I select it on startup I get the no such device error.

```
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
```

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already did that. Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you please include the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID /dev/sd?` and the content of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in you question? It may also help to restore Microsoft's bootloader and then run Boot-Repair to restore Grub to chain-load the now again functional Microsoft bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Boot Repair:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

It works for me whenever I change partitions around .

Regards